# Gmail conversations sorted by last activity

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

I cannot find a way to have my inbox conversation sorted by last activity (sent and received emails). I mean that if I send an email in a conversation that conversation does not appear at the top. That happens only if I receive an email in that conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Up to my knowledge that's not possible through the web interface, but I know for sure that's possible in many e-mail offline clients like [Evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution) or [Claws Mail](https://www.claws-mail.org/).

Answer (score -3):

Sent emails will not appear in conversations. They will appear in the *Sent Items* folder.

Comment: Sent emails do appear in conversations, but they don't affect the order that conversations are sorted in the inbox.